# 2D Array Rotation and Rotating a Point in vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, rotation, 2d, point

I have written a 2D array rotation which works just fine, however I have a point that is focused on a single location on the array and displays a "!" instead of the number when displaying the array.

I had thought that if I checked the point during the array rotation, and then changed the point position to the new array position, the focus point would then rotate with the array, however, the new point location just doesn't match the rotated point.

In the example, I'm focusing on the number "5" (position 1,1), and should always display the "!" instead of "5".

This rotation works for a focal point of 0,0, but not for other points. Can someone please point out to me what I'm doing wrong and explain why the logic doesn't always work?

```
Public Module Module1

    Dim focalX As Integer = 1
    Dim focalY As Integer = 1

    Sub Main()
        Dim src(,) As String =
            {
                {"1", "2", "3"},
                {"4", "5", "6"},
                {"7", "8", "9"},
                {"0", "1", "2"}
            }

        ShowArray(src)

        src = RotatedCW(src)

        ShowArray(src)

        src = RotatedCW(src)

        ShowArray(src)

        src = RotatedCW(src)

        ShowArray(src)

        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit...")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Sub ShowArray(src(,) As String)
        Console.WriteLine(focalX & ", " & focalY)

        For i = 0 To src.GetUpperBound(0)
            For j = 0 To src.GetUpperBound(1)
                If focalX = j And focalY = i Then
                    Console.Write("!" & " ")
                Else
                    Console.Write(src(i, j) & " ")
                End If
            Next
            Console.WriteLine()
        Next

        Console.WriteLine()
    End Sub

    Function RotatedCW(src(,) As String) As String(,)
        Dim maxX As Integer = src.GetUpperBound(0)
        Dim maxY As Integer = src.GetUpperBound(1)

        Dim newArray(maxY, maxX) As String
        For i = 0 To maxX
            For j = 0 To maxY
                newArray(j, maxX - i) = src(i, j)

                If focalX = j And focalY = i Then
                    focalX = maxX - i
                    focalY = j
                End If
            Next
        Next
        Return newArray
    End Function

End Module
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fixed your rotate function logic

```
Function RotatedCW(src(,) As String) As String(,)
    Dim maxX As Integer = src.GetUpperBound(0)
    Dim maxY As Integer = src.GetUpperBound(1)

    Dim oldFocalY = focalY
    focalY = focalX
    focalX = maxX - oldFocalY

    Dim newArray(maxY, maxX) As String
    For i = 0 To maxX
        For j = 0 To maxY
            newArray(j, maxX - i) = src(i, j)
        Next
    Next
    Return newArray
End Function
```

Took the focal point assignments out of the loop because they are only done once and the math is very simple.

Comment: Thank you for this! Just seeing yours finally made me realise what I'd done wrong - put it in the loop, so when it was rotated (correctly) and the loops then encountered the new rotated location, it applied the same math again, sending it somewhere unexpected.